# Create all x,y pairs from two coordinate arrays

Tags: python, list, loops, for-loop

I have 4 lists that I need to iterate over so that I get the following:

```
x     y     a     b
```

Lists a and b are of equal length and I iterate over both using the zip function, the code:

```
for a,b in zip(aL,bL):
    print(a,"\t",b)
```

list x contains 1000 items and list b contains 750 items, after the loop is finished I am supposed to have 750.000 lines.

What is want to achieve is the following:

```
1   1   a   b
1   2   a   b
1   3   a   b
1   4   a   b
.....
1000   745   a   b
1000   746   a   b
1000   747   a   b
1000   748   a   b
1000   749   a   b
1000   750   a   b
```

How can I achieve this? I have tried enumerate and izip but both results are not what I am seeking.

Thanks.

EDIT:

I have followed your code and used since it is way faster. My output now looks like this:

```
[[[  0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00   4.00000000e+01   2.30000000e+01]
  [  1.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00   8.50000000e+01   1.40000000e+01]
  [  2.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00   7.20000000e+01   2.00000000e+00]
  ..., 
  [  1.44600000e+03   0.00000000e+00   9.20000000e+01   4.60000000e+01]
  [  1.44700000e+03   0.00000000e+00   5.00000000e+01   6.10000000e+01]
  [  1.44800000e+03   0.00000000e+00   8.40000000e+01   9.40000000e+01]]]
```

I have now 750 lists and each of those have another 1000. I have tried to flatten those to get 4 values (x,y,a,b) per line. This just takes forever. Is there another way to flatten those?

EDIT2

I have tried

```
np.fromiter(itertools.chain.from_iterable(arr), dtype='int')
```

but it gave and error: setting an array element with a sequence, so I tried

```
np.fromiter(itertools.chain.from_iterable(arr[0]), dtype='int')
```

but this just gave one list back with what I suspect is the whole first list in the array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT v2**

Now using `np.stack` instead of `np.dstack`, and handling file output.

---

This is considerably simpler than the solutions proposed below.

```
import numpy as np
import numpy.random as nprnd

aL = nprnd.randint(0,100,size=10) # 10 random ints
bL = nprnd.randint(0,100,size=10) # 10 random ints

xL = np.linspace(0,100,num=5) # 5 evenly spaced ints
yL = np.linspace(0,100,num=2) # 2 evenly spaced ints

xv,yv = np.meshgrid(xL,yL)

arr = np.stack((np.ravel(xv), np.ravel(yv), aL, bL), axis=-1)

np.savetxt('out.out', arr, delimiter=' ')
```

Using `np.meshgrid` gives us the following two arrays:

```
xv = [[   0.   25.   50.   75.  100.]
     [   0.   25.   50.   75.  100.]]
yv = [[   0.    0.    0.    0.    0.]
     [ 100.  100.  100.  100.  100.]]
```

which, when we ravel, become:

```
np.ravel(xv) = [   0.   25.   50.   75.  100.    0.   25.   50.   75.  100.]
np.ravel(yv) = [   0.    0.    0.    0.    0.  100.  100.  100.  100.  100.]
```

These arrays have the same shape as aL and bL,

```
aL = [74 79 92 63 47 49 18 81 74 32]
bL = [15  9 81 44 90 93 24 90 51 68]
```

so all that's left is to `stack` all four arrays along `axis=-1`:

```
arr = np.stack((np.ravel(xv), np.ravel(yv), aL, bL), axis=-1)
arr = [[   0.    0.   62.   41.]
       [  25.    0.    4.   42.]
       [  50.    0.   94.   71.]
       [  75.    0.   24.   91.]
       [ 100.    0.   10.   55.]
       [   0.  100.   41.   81.]
       [  25.  100.   67.   11.]
       [  50.  100.   21.   80.]
       [  75.  100.   63.   37.]
       [ 100.  100.   27.    2.]]
```

From here, saving is trivial:

```
np.savetxt('out.out', arr, delimiter=' ')
```

**ORIGINAL ANSWER**

```
idx = 0
out = []
for x in xL:
    for y in yL:
        v1 = aL[idx]
        v2 = bL[idx]
        out.append((x, y, v1, v2))
        # print(x,y, v1, v2)
        idx += 1
```

but, it's slow, and only gets slower with more coordinates. I'd consider using the `numpy` package instead. Here's an example with a 2 x 5 dataset.

```
aL = nprnd.randint(0,100,size=10) # 10 random ints
bL = nprnd.randint(0,100,size=10) # 10 random ints

xL = np.linspace(0,100,num=5) # 5 evenly spaced ints
yL = np.linspace(0,100,num=2) # 2 evenly spaced ints


lenx = len(xL) # 5
leny = len(yL) # 2

arr = np.ndarray(shape=(leny,lenx,4)) # create a 3-d array
```

this creates an 3-dimensional array having a shape of 2 rows x 5 columns. On the third axis (length 4) we populate the array with the data you want.

```
for x in range(leny):
    arr[x,:,0] = xL
```

this syntax is a a little confusing at first. You can learn more about it [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html). In short, it iterates over the number of rows and sets a particular slice of the array to `xL`. In this case, the slice we have selected is the zeroth index in all columns of row x. (the `:` means, "select all indices on this axis"). For our small example, this would yield:

```
[[[  0   0   0   0]
  [ 25   0   0   0]
  [ 50   0   0   0]
  [ 75   0   0   0]
  [100   0   0   0]]

 [[  0   0   0   0]
  [ 25   0   0   0]
  [ 50   0   0   0]
  [ 75   0   0   0]
  [100   0   0   0]]]
```

now we do the same for each column:

```
for y in range(lenx):
    arr[:,y,1] = yL

-----

[[[  0   0   0   0]
  [ 25   0   0   0]
  [ 50   0   0   0]
  [ 75   0   0   0]
  [100   0   0   0]]

 [[  0 100   0   0]
  [ 25 100   0   0]
  [ 50 100   0   0]
  [ 75 100   0   0]
  [100 100   0   0]]]
```

now we need to address arrays `aL` and `bL`. these arrays are flat, so we must first `reshape` them to conform to the shape of `arr`. In our simple example, this would take an array of length 10 and reshape it into a 2 x 5 2-dimensional array.

```
a_reshaped = aL.reshape(leny,lenx)
b_reshaped = bL.reshape(leny,lenx)
```

to insert the reshaped arrays into our `arr`, we select the 2nd and 3rd index for all rows and all columns (note the two `:`'s this time:

```
arr[:,:,2] = a_reshaped
arr[:,:,3] = b_reshaped

----

[[[  0   0   3  38]
  [ 25   0  63  89]
  [ 50   0   4  25]
  [ 75   0  72   1]
  [100   0  24  83]]

 [[  0 100  55  85]
  [ 25 100  39   9]
  [ 50 100  43  85]
  [ 75 100  63  57]
  [100 100   6  63]]]
```

this runs considerably faster than the nested loop solution. hope it helps!

Comment: I have tried a nested loop. But this is just giving the position of the each item in their corresponding list. What I want to do it multiply 2 lists with uneven numbers. L1 has 1000 items and L2 has 750. As in the example of the main posts I want each item from L1 to match with each item from L2 so that I end up with 1000*750 = 750.000 items

Comment: Indeed it does, but this is based on 2 lists, in my case I have 4 lists: 1st -> x coordinates, 2st -> y coordinates, 3rd -> v1 and 4th -> v2

Comment: you cannot have 750.000 lines and also zip through lists a and b for each x,y pair. If `len(a)` is 10, you will print out 750.000*10 lines. Can you clarify what you want printed out for lists a and b?

Comment: List 1 has 1000 latitude points, List 2 has 750 longitude points, List 3 has velocity values and list 4 has also velocity values. List 3 and list 4 are equal sized and both have values for 750.000 items each. I need to create a full grid by multiplying 1000*750 which will provide for 750.000 coordinates pairs.

Comment: I have updated my initial post. Looking forward to hearing from you.

Comment: what would you like to accomplish by flattening the data? i.e. are you trying to save it to a file?

Comment: Yes I am trying to save it to a file.

Comment: OK - I've modified the code slightly and added file output.

Comment: I also added a brief explanation of the code for your reference.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need a nested loop for `x` and `y`:

```
for x in yL:
    for y in yL:
        for a, b in zip(aL, bL):
            print "%d\t%d\t%s\t%s" % (x, y, a, b)
```

Comment: Thank you, I think this works for me. How can I make it run in order so that it starts with x=1 and y=1 because now it starts with x=6 and y=1. I want to make sure that it gives me 750.000 lines

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
for i,j in zip(zip(a,b),zip(c,d)):
     print "%d\t%d\t%s\t%s" % (i[0], i[1], j[0], j[1])
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't work for me. This just gives me only 3 sets instead of 175.000